# Encoding is happening while sending parameter from Post request in Jmeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I have a Post request in Jmeter in which, ViewState parameter is passing but value for that parameter is combination of alphabates, number, special characters . so while send that parameter request is encoding the special character for e.g. i have forward slash in paramter so while sending it is converting it to %2F and that leads in failing the request

Solution i have tried is:

- uncheck URL Encode check box
- UTF-8 in content encoding
- for ViewState providing ${__urldecode('${viewState}')} value as Parameter value, which(viewState) i am fetching from previous response
- used replace function in Parameter value

So what i am expecting is while sending Post request parameters should not get encoded.
Can someone please provide solution

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are trying to correlate the variable in the body of the subsequent request(2nd Request).
Try sending the data in "Body Data" instead of parameters. So, it is your variable i.e ${viewState} in "Body Data"

I hope view state is not in the URL.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Body Data tab is disabled in my HTTP post request , able to click for Get request but for Post it is not clickable

Comment: @Pallawi It's disabled because you have parameters specified. You can only use one or the other. This solution works. I also believe the original problem has to do with the "Content-Type" header setting or the "Content-Type" field for the parameter. It may affect how the POST sampler encodes the parameters.